# Is it pronounced 柄【え】? 柄【から】?柄【つか】?

Tags: readings, terminology

Here is a text and video about the cleansing ritual

手水舎【てみずや】

https://www.nippon.com/ja/views/b05205/

which includes the sentence

もう一度【いちど】、左手【ひだりて】を清【きよ】め、最後【さいご】にひしゃくを立【た】てて残【のこ】った水【みず】で柄【?】を清【きよ】める

*Once again, purify your left hand. Finally, stand up the ladle and purify the handle with the remaining water.*

In this context, is 柄 "handle" pronounced 柄【え】 or 柄【から】 or 柄【つか】?

I tried looking it up in a couple of places and could not figure it out.

[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/柄杓](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9F%84%E6%9D%93)

[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/柄/#je-6272](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%9F%84/#je-6272)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd read it as え.

> ひしゃくの[柄]{え}、フライパンの[柄]{え}、[柄]{え}の長い[箒]{ほうき}...

[柄]{え} means "handle, grip" (≈ [取]{と}っ[手]{て}).

---

[柄]{がら} means "pattern, design" (≈ [模様]{もよう}).

> [桜]{さくら}の[柄]{がら}のハンカチ

[柄]{がら} also means "physique, frame" (≈ [体格]{たいかく}), and "nature, quality (of a person or area)"  (≈ [性質]{せいしつ}, [品格]{ひんかく}).

> [柄]{がら}の大きい男 (≈ [大柄]{おおがら}の男)
> [柄]{がら}の悪い地域

---

<sub>I've never seen [柄]{つか}. It seems like it's used for the handle of 武器, such as 刀, 剣, 弓.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Chocolate](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/9831/chocolate):

もう一度、左手を清め、最後にひしゃくを立てて残った水で**柄**を清める。

Hiragana: もういちど、 ひだりて を きよめ、 さいご に ひしゃく を たてて のこった みず で **え** を きよめる。

English: Cleanse the left hand once again, and finally, hold up the ladle and cleanse the **handle** with the remaining water.